# Synonym for "to Accept Blame"

Tags: single-word-requests, synonyms

What is a **one-word** synonym for "to accept blame"?

For example:

> By signing the Treaty of Versailles, Germany accepted blame for World War I.

The synonym should be similar to "to accept responsibility," but should have the **negative connotation** associated with "blame."

Edit: It should also insinuate **reluctance** on behalf of the acceptor.

Comment: yield, give in, etc are distant synonyms.

Comment: Why change what is perfectly fine? reluctantly accepted blame for.I just do not understand these types of questions....

Comment: @Lambie I agree that it is fine to say "reluctantly accepted blame for," but I need something else to say so I don't repeat it.

Comment: Right, so: acknowledged their culpability. My problem is with your single-word thing.:)

Comment: @Lambie Ok. I also think it may have been too much to ask for one-word synonyms. 
 Thanks for your help.

Comment: I can see you are an English speaker and I understand not wanting to repeat oneself. How about this: begrudgingly acknowledged responsibility for? It just seems to get longer, not shorter. :)

Comment: @Lambie I get it; I'll just keep it short and sweet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[**Confess**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/confess):

> [Merriam-Webster]
> *transitive*
> **1** : to tell or make known (something, such as something wrong or damaging to oneself) : ADMIT
>     // he *confessed* his guilt
>
> *intransitive*
> **1 a** : to disclose one's faults
> *specifically* : to unburden one's sins or the state of one's conscience to God or to a priest …
> **2** : ADMIT, OWN
>     // *confess* to a crime

However, the example sentence has to be rephrased slightly:

> By signing the Treaty of Versailles, Germany *confessed* their role in World War I.

---

Confessions can be entirely voluntary, reluctantly made, or even forced:

- She ***reluctantly*** *confessed*.
- It was a ***forced*** *confession*.

---

An informal expression that implies reluctance is [**fess up**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/fess%20up):

> [Merriam-Webster]
> *chiefly US, informal*
> : to admit that one has done something wrong : CONFESS
> // At first he denied everything, but eventually he *fessed up*.
> // He finally *fessed up* about his involvement.
>
> [*thesaurus entry*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/thesaurus/fess%20up)
> **1** to accept the truth or existence of (something) usually reluctantly
> // he *fessed up* to breaking the antique vase only after his guilt was obvious

Note that this is likely too informal to be used in the example sentence in the question.

Comment: Doesn't "confess" imply that Germany was concealing the fact that it was to blame for World War I?

Comment: @JohnB. Not at all. If you apologize to somebody, you are confessing that you are guilty of something, even if it's something that was never hidden. Saying *I'm sorry I hurt you* is a confession.

Comment: You're right; I guess I need to word my question differently.  I think I'm going to edit my question to show that Germany is *reluctant* to confess, but needs to do so.  Nonetheless, thank you for your help.

Comment: @JohnB. Note that confessions can also be forced.

Comment: Yes, but is there a word that can only be used in a context where the confession is forced?

Comment: I upvoted your answer because it does fit the context, but I am still open to any other words that specifically imply that the confession was reluctant.

Comment: @JohnB. I added an informal phrase. (It also refers back to the first word.) But it likely wouldn't be used in your example.

Comment: I agree; "fess up" would be fine in a conversation, but I wouldn't use it in this context.  Thank you for your help.  I'm going to accept your answer because I don't think there is a term that encapsulates (without the use of an adverb) the sense of reluctance for which I am looking.

Comment: `I'm sorry I hurt you` is first and foremost an *apology*.

Comment: @Mari-LouA The main definition of [*apology*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/apology) (or at least the sense I'm referring to) is "an admission of error or discourtesy accompanied by an expression of regret // a public *apology*."  So, you are admitting, or confessing, that you did something wrong (intentionally or not). If you didn't, you wouldn't be apologizing.

Comment: You acknowledge what you did or said was wrong, confessing is moot when the 3rd party knows who to blame. The entire world *knew* that Germany's actions prompted WWI, there was no need for a confession, they demanded retribution and reparation.

Comment: @Mari-LouA A parent might *know* that a child did something bad, but still try to get that child to *confess* to having done it. Many children often deny they did something bad when first asked, because they know it will get them in trouble. Even though the parent knows who's to blame, the child's confession is not a moot point at all. The same is true of police and courts of law, where a confession to a crime makes a significant different in terms of how a person can be sentenced or otherwise treated.

Answer (score 1):

*Shoulder* perfectly fits here.

> **Shoulder (verb):** 
> Shoulder the *blame*, burden, responsibility, cost, etc.
>
> To accept that you are responsible for something bad or difficult
>
> Example: Teachers cannot be expected to shoulder all the blame for poor exam results
>
> [[Cambridge English Dictionary]](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/shoulder)

In your example, you could replace 'accept' with 'shoulder':

> By signing the Treaty of Versailles, Germany shouldered the blame for World War I.

---

> It should also insinuate reluctance on behalf of the acceptor.

[*Acquiesce*](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/acquiesce) means *to accept reluctantly* but it would be strange to use acquiesce in this context because acquiesce does not often have the connotations of *blame.*

Comment: Thanks for "shoulder." I was also thinking about "acquiesce," but it doesn't work with blame.

Answer (score 0):

**Incriminate** or **inculpate** (oneself)

I don't believe there is a single word in English that can meet all of those conditions, but this is the closest thing I can think of. "Incriminate" doesn't necessarily work outside of a legal context, which is why I would generally prefer "inculpate", but I've never actually seen that word used before - it sounds sort of awkward and artificial, even though it isn't too hard to derive by analogy with "exculpate", a word that actually does see ordinary use.

Also, both of these are actions that could be done to someone else; to make it reflexive you'd have to add the prefix "self-", as in "self-incriminate", but this carries the unwanted connotation of *accidentally* revealing one's involvement in the matter, while your example is clearly looking for a word that indicates deliberate admission of guilt.

All in all, I think you're better off with "accept/admit + [noun]" (blame, responsibility, guilt, culpability, etc.) instead of a single word.

Comment: Thank you for your response.  I agree that "confess" and "accept/admit + [noun]" are the best choices.

Answer (score 0):

> [Take the rap (for)](https://www.google.co.uk/amp/s/www.collinsdictionary.com/amp/english/take-the-rap)

is a colloquial near equivalent, although it has the difference that it suggests that the person admitting guilt may not actually be the culprit, but be protecting someone else.

Comment: This is actually quite fitting because (form Germany's perspective) they weren't actually guilty.

Comment: @JohnB. — I take your point (which had occurred to me), but for greater historical accuracy I would change "from Germany's perspective" to something like "from the perspective of certain political factions in Germany". However we're not here to discuss political history.

Comment: I'm just beginning to learn about this stuff, so thank you for correcting me!

Comment: @JohnB. — I didn't mean to say you were out of order or anything. Quite the contrary. Just that I was restraining my own impulse to start a discussion on the Weimar Republik. Nice to find someone on the list with a wider perspective.